# mongoexport query by date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running mongo version 4.2.3 on Linux-Debian

After many attempts, I've succeeded to get a syntax that would not fail for using a query on a date field with mongoexport.

The only syntax that worked for me without exiting mongoexport with an error was this:

```
--query { "receivedTime" : { "$gt" : {"$date":"2021-05-27T00:00:00.000Z"}}}
```

However, this returns no results.

From CLI, the only way I can get results for querying the date field is this:

```
db.rep_audit.find({ "receivedTime":{ "$gt" : new ISODate("2021-05-27T00:00:00.000Z") } }
```

"new ISODate" however was not accepted by the mongoexport tool inside its --query parameter

An idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these formats for using the query in `mongoexport`:

```
--query "{ \"startDate\":{ \"$gte\": { \"$date\": \"2020-02-14T04:07:34Z\" } } }"
--query='{ "startDate": { "$lt": { "$date": "2020-02-28T00:00:00.000Z" } } }'
```

**Querying by *date* field in `mongo` shell:**

For example, if there is a document like this:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "dt" : ISODate("2020-07-05T00:00:00Z") }
```

You can query it with any of the two ways:

```
db.collection.find( { dt: ISODate("2020-07-05T00:00:00Z") } )
db.collection.find( { dt: new Date("2020-07-05T00:00:00Z") } )
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, apparently the "$date" format for the --query parameter for mongoexport gives the same results as ISODate in mongoshell. Using however the $date in mongoshell does not work (that is,  it returns zero results), just like ISODate does not work for mongoexprot (gives an error).

Comment: What have you tried in `mongo` shell? Please post the query _and_ the data you had queried. Is there an error? What was your expectation? Please provide / include all these details. **NOTE**: The formats (of the date) used in `mongoexport` and `mongo` shell are different, as they are different tools - you cannot use the same formats in them (That may be the reason you are getting the error).